# Limit on hops in IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv4

I was reading [IPv4](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt), and in it it specifies time to live, aka TTL or "max hops" in IPv6 since this is [what it really represents](https://superuser.com/questions/444222/can-a-router-reduce-ttl-value-by-more-than-one).

My concern is that this value is 8 bits, thus has a max value of 255, which is decremented at each "hop" through a Gateway. That means that any two points in any network using IPv4 have to have 254 gateways between them or less.

This just seems like a pretty limiting restriction. I mean I guess using trace it looks like most things end up being 20-30 hops max, and due to the branching shape of the internet you still can cover a lot of space in 20-30 hops, but still, are there any protocols for networks with trails between nodes of length greater than 255? Or do we just assume that that's not practical?

I mean I can think of some unofficial ways to get around this (say using options, where once it reaches 0 instead of deleting itself it goes back to 255 and a second 8-bit TTL value contained in options is decremented. Eventually if that second 8-bit value reaches 0 and the original TTL reaches 0 it will still be deleted as normal), but I'm wondering if there's protocols already in existence I could use.

Comment: Are you having a problem with this or trying to learn something?

Comment: I'm simulating IPv4/BGP4 to test various situations under loads to have a better understanding of the internet's performance, however this limits my simulation. As was pointed out below it's probably  a reasonable restriction though, since the "diamater of the internet doesn't grow that much," it wouldn't be a realistic simulation if the diameter is that large, as one example of many restrictions I'm still learning that could potentially make it more realistic.

So long story short both, my simulation had a problem of being restricted by this but that turned into learning something I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diameter of the internet doesn't grow that much. The Internet grows but is also well interconnected so the maximum path length is pretty constant. It is like [6-degrees-of-separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation) but on a larger scale. My guess would be that with a TTL of 32 you can reach >99.9% of the Internet and a TTL of 64 will get you everywhere. Unfortunately I can't find any more recent research than [Diameter of the
World-Wide Web (1999)](http://www3.nd.edu/~networks/Publication%20Categories/03%20Journal%20Articles/Computer/Diameter_Nature%20401,%20130-131%20(1999).pdf).

A longer path would also increase the latency so much that the speed and response times would become unacceptable to current standards.